# Usage of extern functions for portability

Tags: c, extern

I have seen some libraries for microcontrollers that do a special job like controlling an SPI device. They define extern functions with a context pointer  for byte sending and pin configuration which the user must implement. Is this a good practice to do so?

Some others use function pointers inside their context but these pointer may be very expensive and some older compilers do not allow function pointers with a lot of parameters due to parameter passing restrictions (I remember this from the C51 compiler)

Comment: In my opinion better is using function pointers, because it can be NULL, user not must implement this if dont want use. MUST implement is wrong idea.
Not have to be a lot of arguments in function pointers, can be replaced with scructure or `void*`.

Comment: What do you mean with "extern function"? An function with `extern` linkage? A function pointer which is global? Can you give a code example?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Using extern functions that need to be implemented by a higher layer is a very efficient way to use callbacks. Especially when they are called frequently, they have a lower performance penalty than function pointers, which need to be dereferenced. However, function pointers to callback functions are more flexible, as you can allow them to be null. Furthermore, it is possible to change them at execution time.